# apache logs https GET parameters?

Tags: apache, logging

If I request a page like https://www.example.com/?pippo=123, what would appear in the apache logs?
I know that POST parameters are not logged, but for GET ones?

Tkz!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log entry will look like this:

```
123.239.125.171 - - [29/Apr/2010:13:15:48 +0100] "GET /?pippo=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 8057
```

If you requested a specific page:

```
123.239.125.171 - - [29/Apr/2010:13:15:48 +0100] "GET /myPage.php?pippo=123 HTTP/1.1" 200 8057
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs are stored in a file in the following location

```
/var/log/apache2/access.log
```

and a typical log entry looks something like this

```
122.176.153.175 - - [04/Apr/2014:04:48:33 +0000] "GET /analytics.gif?testing=1&prod=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 323 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36"
```